# Why is she referred to as Gendered Child?

Tags: hollow-knight

Hornet is sometimes referred to by others as Gendered Child. Why is that? There are enough female bugs in the world for it not to be *that* rare.

Answer (score 9):

Warning: Spoilers ahead. Feel free to read at your own risk.

Hornet is made from the Void, just like the main character and the other Vessels. However unlike the Vessels, Hornet was made at request from Herrah the Beast in exchange for Herrah becoming a dreamer. While the exact circumstances of her creation are not clearly defined, both the White Lady and Herrah herself, consider Hornet to be their daughter.

The specific naming of "Gendered Child" sterns from the fact that Vessels canonically have no gender, due to the fact that they are empty shells only designed to hold the infection. Given Hornet is also made from the Void, this makes her the only creation from the Void to canonically have a gender. (The kingsmoulds are simple automatons and the Collector is ambiguous enough in both voice and behavior).

Comment: One possible caveat: It could be that Hornet isn't made from void but is the direct child of the king and herrah instead - providing the reason why she differs from the other empty shells.

Comment: There is nothing in the lore that would indicate Hornet is made from the void, no lore reason for her to be from the void, and plenty of evidence that she isn't. She's the only known child of Pale King to have a gender - in particular, because she isn't a vessel, she was never created with intention of infusing her with void, and has a different mother than all the vessels. She's just a brave, talented, naturally hatched female bug - and half-blood pale-being. Why would she need to be void to gain that nickname anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Hornet is not [void](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Void)<sup>1</sup>. Go watch [Mossbag's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JKUolxcH10) on this topic as well as a more recent video of his about the upcoming game [Silksong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHQmOOorljQ).

Hornet is called the Gendered Child because she is the only daughter of the Pale King with a gender. Also, Hornet wasn't made at request of Herrah, she IS her daughter. Her and Pale King...well, yeah.

The reason the White Lady refers to her as her daughter is because she is also a bride of the Pale King, and, since Herrah became a dreamer, the White Lady had to raise Hornet. Hornet isn't void because she says she and the Knight, or Ghost, whichever you want to call them, do not share an emptiness. Guess what another word for emptiness is? A void.

Also, there is no evidence to show her egg was thrown into the abyss, like the Vessels. That is how the Vessels were made of void. To make one: Hatch an egg, then throw it into the Abyss. There is also just no reason for Hornet to be made of void! If she has a gender, she cannot be hollow, so why would the Pale King put it in there?! Hornet also wasn't a union of two Pale Beings, like the Vessels were, so the Pale King wouldn't even want to try to make her hollow<sup>2</sup>.

Also, if Herrah wanted a kid so badly, she probably wouldn't want her to have no emotions, because the whole reason she agreed to be a dreamer was so that her child could be of 'higher birth'. So. Hornet isn't void, and that's why she is gendered.

<sup>1</sup>: To "be void" is to originate from the [abyss](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Abyss).

<sup>2</sup>: Beings incapable of feeling emotion, having willpower, thinking, or empathizing are said to be "Hollow".